# React TypeError: " this is undefined ", function inside function call not working

Tags: reactjs

Trying to call `addChildNodeNext` method in `addChildNode` function, but

```
result = this.addChildNodeNext(item.childrens,CurrentID)
```

gives error of `this is undefined`. I have already bind both function in constructor.

```
class TestAdd extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.addChildNode = this.addChildNode.bind(this)
    this.addChildNodeNext = this.addChildNodeNext.bind(this)
  }

  addChildNodeNext = (nodeList, CurrentID) => {
    alert(`Self ${nodeList} : ${CurrentID}`)
    return nodeList
  }

  addChildNode = (nodeList, CurrentID) => {
    const { childIndex } = this.state
    let index = childIndex
    const newTree = nodeList.filter(function (item) {
      alert(`Self ${item.name} : ${CurrentID}`)
      index += 1
      let result = ""
      if (item.name === CurrentID) {
        const newName = `child_${childIndex}_${CurrentID}`
        result = item.childrens.push({ name: newName, parent: newName, childrens: [] })
      } else if (item.childrens.length > 0) {
        result = this.addChildNodeNext(item.childrens, CurrentID)
      } else {
        result = item
      }
      return result
    });
    this.setState({ childIndex: index })
    this.setState({ treeNode: newTree })
  }

}

export default TestAdd;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a regular function in your `.filter` method. This is why you lose `this` context there. Also, you don't need to bind your functions in the constructor because you are using arrow functions.

```
addChildNode = (nodeList, CurrentID) => {
    const { childIndex } = this.state
    let index = childIndex
    const newTree = nodeList.filter(function (item) { // <--- HERE
      alert(`Self ${item.name} : ${CurrentID}`)
      index += 1
      let result = ""
      if (item.name === CurrentID) {
        const newName = `child_${childIndex}_${CurrentID}`
        result = item.childrens.push({ name: newName, parent: newName, childrens: [] })
      } else if (item.childrens.length > 0) {
        result = this.addChildNodeNext(item.childrens, CurrentID)
      } else {
        result = item
      }
      return result
    });
    this.setState({ childIndex: index })
    this.setState({ treeNode: newTree })
  }
```

You can replace it with an arrow function:

```
addChildNode = (nodeList, CurrentID) => {
    const { childIndex } = this.state
    let index = childIndex
    const newTree = nodeList.filter(item => {
      alert(`Self ${item.name} : ${CurrentID}`)
      index += 1
      let result = ""
      if (item.name === CurrentID) {
        const newName = `child_${childIndex}_${CurrentID}`
        result = item.childrens.push({ name: newName, parent: newName, childrens: [] })
      } else if (item.childrens.length > 0) {
        result = this.addChildNodeNext(item.childrens, CurrentID)
      } else {
        result = item
      }
      return result
    });
    this.setState({ childIndex: index })
    this.setState({ treeNode: newTree })
  }
```

Comment: You are welcome. If this answer solved your problem, just consider accepting it, please.